# How to know who is the BigQuery view creator?

Tags: google-bigquery

There is a view in a BigQuery project, and nobody knows who has created it. Is there a way to get known who did it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you should be able to find in your project's [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs).  You should look for the `tables.insert` call that created the view.

The view's creator is not stored as part of its metadata, so the BigQuery API doesn't return this value as a part of `tables.get` or any other API call.

Comment: that worked perfectly! @norgematos - the data point you will be looking for is under protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail

Answer (score 0):

Another option is via `INFORMAION_SCHEMA.JOBS`

```sql
SELECT
 *
FROM
  `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
WHERE
  creation_time > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  AND statement_type = 'CREATE_VIEW'
ORDER BY creation_time DESC
```

You would need to pick the right region and adjust date filter if needed.

According to Google docs:
This view contains currently running jobs and the job history of the past 180 days.